# RSpec/Capybara test for params fails because of reversed order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm writing my first RSpec test and running in to a bit of a wall. Here is what I have.

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "submit a search request" do

  scenario "submits a search to the correct path" do
    visit root_path
    within("#search-form") do
    fill_in 'search', :with => 'mysearch'
  end

   click_button 'search-submit'
   current_url.should == search_url(:utf8 => '✓', :search => 'mysearch')

  end
end
```

The params are returned in alphabetical order. If I change the name of :search to start with any letter after 'u', it passes. Here is the error message

```
 1) the map search submits a search request to the map controller
 Failure/Error: current_url.should == search_url(:utf8=> '✓', :search => 'mysearch')
   expected: "http://www.example.com/map?search=mysearch&utf8=%E2%9C%93"
        got: "http://www.example.com/map?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=mysearch"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare each query parameter separately.

To get the params from the url, do something like this:

```
url = "http://www.example.com/map?search=mysearch&utf8=%E2%9C%93"
query = URI.parse(url).query # => "search=mysearch&utf8=%E2%9C%93"
CGI::parse query             # => {"search"=>["mysearch"], "utf8"=>["✓"]}
```